# Trying to sign up (from a web page) on Firebase, using Facebook

Tags: facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

I have a small web site where users can sign in on Firebase, using email and password.

I uses this code:

```
<script>

function SignUpWithMailPSW(email,pswRdmSeq) {
    ....
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pswRdmSeq).then(function(user) {
        ....
    }
    ... useful things irrelevant to the question.
}

</script>
```

And it works well.

Now I want to provide the option for the users to sign in using Facebook.

To get started I found [this document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/facebook-login). And to experiment I did something based on what I read, just a small test page. Here is the code:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="content-type" CONTENT="text/html; CHARSET=UTF-8">
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.5/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.5/firebase-auth.js"></script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<script>
// Your web app's Firebase configuration
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "ABCDEF-APIKEY-12345",
    authDomain: "myapp.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://myapp.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "myapp",
    storageBucket: "myapp.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "123456789",
    appId: "1:987654321:web:xy2122k98xyxy8988"
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
</script>

<b>TEST ONLY PAGE !!!</b>

<script>

var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();

function SignUpWithFB() {

    // var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();

    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
    // This gives you a Facebook Access Token. You can use it to access the Facebook API.
    var token = result.credential.accessToken;
    // The signed-in user info.
    var user = result.user;
    // ...
    }).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // The email of the user's account used.
    var email = error.email;
    // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
    var credential = error.credential;
    // ...
    });
}

SignUpWithFB();

</script>

<b>TEST ONLY PAGE !!!</b>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

But it does almost nothing.

Precisely, here is what appears in the browser when loading the page:

[image]

Obviously as one can see it is not yet quite working.
But I would like to know what I need to change (or to check) in order to have a prompt giving me a chance to sign up with Facebook.

Comment: Have you correctly configured it in the firebase console with your app id etc?

Comment: Yes I think I did: App ID and App Secret I got from Facebook. And then the OAuth redirect URI copy part which was at first hard to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things to be noted are

1. Create a new Firebase Project (or use the existing one) and navigate to *project overview*  where you'll get the firebase configuration object (namely the **firebaseConfig** ) Copy that (either CDN or the config) and paste it in the script powering your site.
2. For using authentication feature of firebase add the Auth-SDK of firebase 
   below the main firebase script (in the following order)

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.5/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.5/firebase-auth.js"></script>
```

2. Go to the Authentication tab and then Sign-in methods and look for *Authorised domains* .Make sure the **URL** with which you are testing this site is there, if not ,add that. for example : *127.0.0.1* for localhost .
3. Finally Enable what-ever sign-in methods you want or trying to test, by changing its status from disable(i.e default) to enable and use the corresponding *provider* object.

Note: For FB option you need to give the AppID and App Secret, which you can easily grab from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/?authuser=0) .

*However if you are just trying out things and doesn't have the AppID  and secret, Just follow first 2 steps and skip other. Doing so will result in a popup which will be closed by itself (which makes sense as the fb option is disabled)*

Comment: Based on some answer and comment I got, I reviewed my code., did some rechecking, modifications and updated my post to reflect that. But it is not yet quite working.

Comment: hi @Michel , I would like to know if you followed all the steps mentioned in answer above ??

Comment: Yes I tried, step 2 was probably the most useful for me. Finally I just discovered something which I had not properly copied in the FB developer console. Now I made one more progress. I seems like I can sign in using FB and this is the first thing I wanted to do. But then I guess I should be able to make use of the result that I get in the callback, and I do not know how to do this yet.

Comment: Happy to see it worked! ... would you mind to share the code ?

Comment: The code is the one you can see in the post, I had just missed the point 3. c in the document I mention in the post. That is why it did not work. Thanks for your help.
I am now challenging the next step (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57441363/using-a-web-page-after-sign-up-on-firebase-with-facebook).

Comment: @Michel check if this is what you are looking https://stackoverflow.com/a/57441929/9312233