# Using a web page, after sign up on Firebase, with Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

I have a small web site where users can sign in on Firebase, using email and password.

I uses this code:

```
<script>

function SignUpWithMailPSW(email,pswRdmSeq) {
    ....
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pswRdmSeq).then(function(user) {
        ....
    }
    ... useful things irrelevant to the question.
}

</script>
```

Now users can also sign in using Facebook.

To get started I found [this document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/facebook-login). And to experiment I did something based on what I read, just a small test page. Here is the code:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="content-type" CONTENT="text/html; CHARSET=UTF-8">
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.5/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.5/firebase-auth.js"></script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<script>
// Your web app's Firebase configuration
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "ABCDEF-APIKEY-12345",
    authDomain: "myapp.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://myapp.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "myapp",
    storageBucket: "myapp.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "123456789",
    appId: "1:987654321:web:xy2122k98xyxy8988"
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
</script>

<b>TEST ONLY PAGE !!!</b>

<script>

var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();

function SignUpWithFB() {

    // var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();

    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
    // This gives you a Facebook Access Token. You can use it to access the Facebook API.
    var token = result.credential.accessToken;
    // The signed-in user info.
    var user = result.user;
    // ...
    }).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // The email of the user's account used.
    var email = error.email;
    // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
    var credential = error.credential;
    // ...
    });
}

SignUpWithFB();

</script>

<b>TEST ONLY PAGE !!!</b>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

At this point it is starting to work.

But I would like to know how to make use of the *result* (and *result.credential*) parameter that we get in the call back function (or promise?):

```
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {});
```

I did not find anything significant about this result variable (type, fields, use, ..etc..) searching the net.

Some hints would be very useful.

Comment: let me know if this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

The ***result*** variable which you are getting in the ***then*** part of the promise , is an **object** (type) holding all the information about the user. And contains a lot of properties on itself,  using which you can get all of these data very easily.

Naming a few important ones

- *displayName* : Gives you User's display name
- *email* : Gives you the user's email ID
- *emailVerified* : Tells you whether the email-ID is verified or not
- *metadata* : Itself a object containing info such as LastSignInTime and creationTime
- *photoURL* : A URL to the picture of user, the current one.
- *uid* : (very useful) Unique ID associated with each user, which will let you do many authentication ahead.

Note : To list and check all these property , try outputting it in console 
     `console.log(result);`

Answer (score 0):

The [`signInWithPopup` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#sign-inwith-popup) is declared as:

> ```
> signInWithPopup(provider: AuthProvider): Promise<UserCredential>
> ```

So it returns `Promise<UserCredential>`. This means that in your `then` callback you get a [`UserCredential` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.html#usercredential), which is declared as:

> ```
> Optional additionalUserInfo?: AdditionalUserInfo | null
> credential: AuthCredential | null
> Optional operationType?: string | null
> user: User | null
> ```

So it has a `user` and a `credential` property, and *may* also have `additionalUserInfo` and `operationType`.

For more information on each of these, keep following the links in the reference documentation.